# How to update a label throughout a function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, translate

I am trying to update a label throughout a function (def submit), but the label only shows after the function has finished running. I have tried different methods to solve this problem. But, I am still not able to solve the issue. Can anyone help me?

My attempts: to update label

## label

```
self.label = root.Label(self, text="His Windows Use Audio For Translate ").pack()
```

## 1

```
label.configure(text=chars)
```

## 2

`label.pack_forget() label["text"]="2. Yay!! I am updated"`

code :
Note: I copied his code from another website to practice my coding skills

```
class VoiceTrans(root.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        # here
        self.var_char = None
        self.text_var = root.StringVar()
        self.lang_var = root.StringVar()
        root.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = root.Label(self, text="His Windows Use Audio For Translate ")
        self.label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.lang_label = root.Label(self, text='Voice Translation', font=('calibre', 10, 'bold'))
        self.lang_label.pack(padx=1, pady=1)

        new_windows = ttk.Button(self, text='  START  ', command=self.submit)
        new_windows.place(x=165, y=255)

        self.switch_window_button = ttk.Button(
            self, text="Return to menu", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage)
        )
        self.switch_window_button.pack(side="bottom", fill=root.X)
        # below function quite over-all window
        self.switch_window_button = ttk.Button(
            self, text="Quite", command=lambda: controller.destroy_root()
        )
        self.switch_window_button.pack(side="bottom", fill=root.X)

    def set_label(self, chars):
        var_char = ttk.Label(self, foreground='red')
        var_char.pack(padx=0, pady=1)
        var_char.configure(text=chars)
    def submit(self):
        flag = 0

        # Capture Voice
        # takes command through microphone
        def take_command():
            r = sr.Recognizer()
            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                self.set_label("listening.....")
                # listening = ttk.Label(self, text="listening.....", foreground='red')
                # listening.pack(padx=0, pady=1)
                # # listening['text'] = "listening....."

                print("listening.....")

                r.pause_threshold = 1
                audio = r.listen(source)

            try:
                # listening.pack_info()
                # # recognizing_voice = ttk.Label(self, foreground='red')
                # # recognizing_voice.pack(padx=0, pady=1)
                # listening['text'] = "Recognizing....."


                print("Recognizing.....")

                query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')

                self.user_label = ttk.Label(self, text=f"The User said {query}\n", font=('calibre', 10,))
                self.user_label.pack(padx=140, pady=195)

                print(f"The User said {query}\n")

            except Exception as e:
                again_voice = ttk.Label(self, foreground='red')
                again_voice.pack(padx=0, pady=1)
                again_voice['text'] = "say that again please....."

                print("say that again please.....")

                return "None"
            return query

        # Input from user
        # Make input to lowercase
        query = take_command()
        while query == "None":
            query = take_command()

        def destination_language():

            chose_lang = ttk.Label(self, foreground='red')
            chose_lang.pack(padx=0, pady=1)
            chose_lang['text'] = "What language would you like to translate to?"

            print("Enter the language in which you want to convert : Ex. Hindi , English , etc.")
            print()

            # Input destination language in
            # which the user wants to translate
            to_lang = take_command()
            while to_lang == "None":
                to_lang = take_command()
            to_lang = to_lang.lower()
            return to_lang

        to_lang = destination_language()

        # Mapping it with the code
        while to_lang not in lang_list_voice:
            lang.destroy()
            lang = ttk.Label(self, foreground='red')
            lang.pack(padx=0, pady=1)
            lang['text'] = "Wrong input"

            print(
                "Wrong input")
            print()
            to_lang = destination_language()

        to_lang = lang_list_voice[lang_list_voice.index(to_lang) + 1]

        # invoking Translator

        text = trans_text(to_lang_tran=to_lang, text_for_tran=query)

        # to speak the translated text into the
        # destination language which is stored in to_lang.
        # Also, we have given 3rd argument as False because
        # by default it speaks very slowly
        speak = gTTS(text=text, lang=to_lang, slow=False)

        # Using save() method to save the translated
        # speech in capture_voice.mp3
        speak.save("captured_voice.mp3")

        # Using OS module to run the translated voice.
        playsound('captured_voice.mp3')
        os.remove('captured_voice.mp3')

        # returning Output
        return text
```

Comment: `self.label` is None - the result of calling `.pack()`, NOT the actual Label.  You need  to do the geometry management as a separate statement if you want to save a reference to the widget itself.

Comment: If `self.label` has been properly created, then it's `self.label.config(text="...")`

Comment: If the question is about modifying a widget, the [mcve] really only needs the widget, a button to change it, and enough extra code to make it work. We don't need all of the other code that's unrelated to the question being asked. If what you're really asking is about an error message, please include the error message after first searching this site for similar error messages.